# How to upcast from object to the specific type it really is?

Tags: java, jdbc, resultset

Im trying to use the method `getObject` from `ResultSet`, which returns the value of the column but as a generic `Object`, really the underlying object is of the kind of the column, that is, a `String`, a `Date` .. .

I would need the actual class, because i'm using some polimorphic code that behaves differently depending on the type of the value returned.

```
Object data = resultSet.getObject(columnIndex);
someOperation(data);

public void someOperation(Number);
public void someOperation(String);
public void someOperation(Object);
```

With this code, only the `someOperation(Object)` function is called. Is there anyway to automatically upcast the Object to it's real class. I've seen some code that does this, but I can't find it anymore.

`(Date)value` is not what I wan't. **I don't know if with generics this can be achieved.**

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know that .NET framework has a `Cast` method to cast an object to the type that the `Type` object specifies. So I think there should be one in Java too. You can use `data.getClass()` to get the real type of the object and maybe use an equivalent of the `Cast` method to cast it.

Comment: It is not polymorphic, you are just overloading a method. If you do not know what is coming from a columnIndex you have to try all possible options with instanceof, but if you do, use getString, getInt and other methods of resultset class so you won't have to downcast.

Comment: Yes it is, overloading is a kind of polymorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Just to Correct your comment here :

> Is there anyway to automatically upcast the Object to it's real class.

You can not upcast an Object's object as it is already being referred by highest class in the hierarchy. All you can do is to downcast it from here. Before downcasting you need to check the IS-A relationship of the object to the type being casted to using `instanceof` operator. You may use this approach.

```
Object data = resultSet.getObject(columnIndex);
checkTypeAnPerformOperation(data);
.
.
.
checkTypeAnPerformOperation(Object o){

    if(o instanceof String){
        //call the String specific operation 
        someOperation((String)o);
    }
    if(o instanceof Number){
        //call the Number specific operation 
        someOperation((Number)o);
    }
    else{
        //call the Object specific operation 
        someOperation(o);
    }
}
public void someOperation(Number); //Definition to Number specific methods
public void someOperation(String); //Definition to String specific methods
public void someOperation(Object); //Definition to Object specific methods
```

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. Do use it for text that is code, and do use quote formatting for text that is quoted.

Comment: This is the approach I've finally taken. Thanks.